# How to Manage a Navigation Menu in NextJS with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, graphql, next.js

I'm building a NextJS app using headless WordPress with GraphQL. It's not clear from the documentation where I should be calling the query to create the site navigation.
https://github.com/lfades/next.js/tree/examples/cms-wordpress/examples/cms-wordpress

The navigation is controlled dynamically by WordPress Menus (`Appearance > Menus`) on the backend and I can successfully access these `menuItems` via GraphQL without any issue on the `index.js` and `posts/[slug].js` page templates in Next JS.

```
// index.js
export default function Index({ primaryMenu = [] }) {
   return (
     <Layout>
         <Header> 
          {primaryMenu.map((item, index) => {
             return (<a href={item.url}>{item.label}</a>)
          )}
         </Header>
     </Layout>
   );

}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const primaryMenu = await getPrimaryMenu(); // Get menu via GraphQL
  return {
    props: { primaryMenu },
  };
}
```

The issue I'm having with this is I am repeating the `getStaticProps` function on each template and I should be able to use some sort of global query for this, either in the `<header/>` component itself or another method. I'm unable to find documentation on how to do this and it doesn't work in components.

Any guidance (or examples) on where a global query such as a dynamic Navigation query would live in a NextJS app is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do it:

1. You can menuItems query with useQuery() from @apollo/client inside the Layout component so that its available to all pages which are wrapped inside the Layout. However the problem with this is that, there will be a load time and the data won't be prefetched and readily available like we can do with getServerSideProps() ( at page level ). Because this will be at component level.

   import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

   export default function Layout () {

   const { loading, data } = useQuery( GET_MENU_QUERY )
   return {...}
   }
2. You can use [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) that uses caching strategy. There is [blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/data-fetching-in-react-and-next-js-with-useswr-to-impress-your-friends-at-parties-ec2db732ca6b) that explains how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I battled this for a while (for JD site) with redux and wp rest, but I think theory should be the same for gql + apollo client.

You need to override Next App _app with a custom class that extends App.

And you might need to inject an instance of apollo client into AppContext using a HOC. [I used this wrapper for Redux](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/master/packages/wrapper/src/index.tsx). Would need to be modelled after that.

Edit: ([Looks like someone has made it already](https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo))

```
// export default withRedux(makeStore)(MyApp);
export default withApollo(apolloClient)(MyApp); ???
```

Then in your App getInitialProps, you can make query to get menu. By default apollo client query will grab cached value if it's in the cache store already I believe.

```
  static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
    const { isServer,  pathname, apollo? } = appContext.ctx;

    // do menu query
    const menu = apollo.query???

    // Redux version
    // const state = store.getState();
    // let main_menu = state.menu;
    // if (!state.menu) {
    //  const menu = await apiService().getMenu("main");
    //  main_menu = menu;
    //  store.dispatch({ type: "SET_MENU", payload: menu });
    // }

    ...

    // call the page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
    const initialProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

    const appProps: any = {
      ...initialProps,
      menu: main_menu
    };

    return appProps;

  }
```

Now menu is in the page props of the App Component, which can be passed down. 
Or you can use apollo client to make the query again in a child component. So when you make the query again, in header or whatever, it will take the cached response provided it's the same query.

I made an endpoint for menus that included the template name + post slug along with the menu items and mapped the wp templates to next routes.

```
const menu = useSelector((state: any) => state.menu);
const menuItems = menu.map((item: any) => {
    const path = getTemplatePath(item.template);
    return (
      <Link key={item.slug} href={`/${path}`} as={`/${item.slug}`} scroll={false}>
        <a>{item.title}</a>
      </Link>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Yes, `getInitialProps` does work, but NextJS docs makes it seem like it will soon be deprecated so I'm hesitant to use it.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Comment: @DarrenCooney That didn't exist when I did this, so I don't know. I don't think deprecated, but warned because it can't statically generate anymore. Because including it means data requests are required to render the pages. Which in this case it does right, because it needs to ask WP for data prior to rendering (ie. the menu).

Comment: But it's still possible to cache and serve rendered pages. I deployed to now(vercel) and in config added the headers to cache and revalidate. `"headers": { "cache-control": "s-maxage=1,stale-while-revalidate" },`